# Jupyter notebooks export to .pdf

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to export my notebook to .pdf.

The steps I have done so far:

- Installed pandoc
- Instaleld MikTex 2.9
- Added pandoc to System variables (adress to pandoc.exe)

Now when I attempt to download my notebook as .pdf, I get this:

[image]

If I click Install, the window appears again.

I am working with Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to properly set the path. Now the .pdf download is working.